# How to use sed to insert after pattern conditionally

Tags: bash, sed, ansible

Please help me understand the more advanced syntax of sed. The way I understand it, I can use two sed commands in a single string to both search for pattern and then conditionally insert after that pattern. here is the goal. I have a file like this:

```
[PATTERN]
String
```

I need sed to insert "String" after [PATTERN] only if "String" doesn't exist.

"String" uses Ansible variables and basically looks like this:

```
{{ hostname.droplet.name }} ansible_ssh_host={{ hostname.droplet.ip_address }}
```

this translates to

```
hostname ansible_ssh_host=X.X.X.X
```

So ultimately I will have the following real world (non conceptual) example:

```
[DROPLETS]
ilovetacos ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1
```

If there is not a matching line below [DROPLETS] then append the line. If the particular hostname line already exists, then dont add the line again.

I can handle the first part:

```
sed '/\[DROPLETS\]/a STRING' inventory
```

Now here is my first problem. I dont know how to handle the ansible variables inside the sed command? Perhaps like this?

```
sed '/\[DROPLETS\]/a "{{ hostname.droplet.name }} ansible_ssh_host={{ hostname.droplet.ip_address }}"' inventory
```

The next part is to add the conditional check. I had considered just greping for the line first and then piping to sed, but it seems there is a better way to do all of this using a single sed command. Can someone please help me with this more advanced syntax?

Thanks

Comment: Why not replace `sed` with Ansible's `lineinfile` module call?

Comment: Yes I totally agree, but ironically the whole reason I am attempting it this way is because we discovered a bug in the lineinfile module. Thats a whole other can of worms, but basically, the lineinfile module was failing to write all output to the file despite verifying the contents of the variables. We tested everything. Thought maybe the file was locked. Thought maybe the variables were incomplete, etc. We ultimately had to abandon the module and opt for a pure shell option. I don't like doing this way at all... Feels wrong and against everything Ansible is, but so far we have no choice.

Comment: Proper suggestion though!

Comment: So you appear to be dynamically building an inventory file, based on your example. That suggests that there may be any number of hosts under `[DROPLETS]` so you are not necessarily even just looking for a match directly below? That is going to be quite tricky to reliably solve. Before you get too far into this, have you considered writing a dynamic inventory script instead? (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory-scripts)

Comment: totally agree with @clockworknet but if that's not your situation for some reason, then my follow-on suggestion is to use an actual scripting language, because sed really isn't designed to do very many "stateful" things. You can probably also use `awk`, which has more rich variables, if you are really adamant against using a scripting language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still stand by my comment, that dependent on your use case,  using [dynamic inventory scripts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory-scripts) is likely the way to go. However, **if it is the case that the line you are looking to add can only ever exist at most once in the file** this may meet your requirements:

(Credit to Konstantin Suvorov as this includes a technique taken [from his website](https://ansibledaily.com/idempotent-shell-command-in-ansible/))

```
- name: Build inventory string
  set_fact:
    inventory_string: "{{ hostname.droplet.name }} ansible_ssh_host={{ hostname.droplet.ip_address }}"
    inventory_file: /tmp/sssd.conf
- name: Add inventory string to inventory file if necessary
  shell: |
    grep "^{{ inventory_string }}" {{ inventory_file }} ||
    sed -i '/\[DROPLETS\]/a {{ inventory_string }}' {{ inventory_file }}
  register: output
  changed_when: output.stdout != inventory_string
```

A few things going on in the `shell` task:

- The `shell` command defines two commands, separated by `||`. This a Unix shell construct that says the command that follows will only run if the command that precedes it fails. Then we use `grep` to see if the string already exists. If `grep` fails to find it, then the `sed` command to add it is run
- Without specifying a `changed_when` condition, the task will always report 'Changed'. We `register` the output from the task. In the case that `grep` finds your string, the `stdout` will simply contain your string, so we can check for its existence to figure out whether the `sed` command was triggered.

Comment: This is going to work. I'm just running into lots of other problems, but ultimately this solved my specific ask. Thank you!